# Jquery Radio Button Check Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery to store the value of a checked set of radio buttons into a variable and it works fine, but the issue I'm having is when someone decides to skip the question (skip the set of radio buttons -i.e. don't select an option) the value that is returned in the variable is 'undefined'. I would like to have the value returned as blank (no value) if someone decides to skip a set of radio buttons. Is there an easy method to do this in Jquery?

**Jquery:**

```
`var raq1= $('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val();`
```

**HTML:**

```
`<input type="radio"  name="q1" id="qn1i5" value="5">
 <input type="radio"  name="q1" id="qn1i4" value="4">
 <input type="radio"  name="q1" id="qn1i3" value="3">
 <input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i2" value="2">
 <input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i1" value="1">`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is check whether `$('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val()` exists. If it exists, set that value to `raq1`. If it doesn't, you simply set `raq1` to be an empty string.

This can be done with the following **[ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val() ? $('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val() : ''
```

And can be seen in the following:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var raq1 = $('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val() ? $('input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked').val() : '';
  console.log(raq1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i5" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i4" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i3" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="qn1i1" value="1">

<button>Get Values</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using vanilla javascript with jQuery together?

Comment: For the button selector? It really doesn't matter. I've just gone with personal preference.

Comment: @obsidian Age, Thanks for the tip. I"m getting an error though:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined.

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: @Smith -- That's because you don't have a `<button>` element on your page. I'm not sure how you're actually **triggering** your function, but don't worry about that -- it's only used for my example. You may want a `getElementById` instead, for example. The `var raq1` is the only line you're interested in :)

Comment: Just validated that everything is working as expected. Thanks!